# Render a View Script to a Variable

Tags: zend-framework

How can I render a view script into a variable within an action controller?

I want to render a view and insert it into a database table as a string.

I am using Zend Framework 1.11

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From your controller you can do:

```
$view = new Zend_View();
$view->some_var = "some_value";
// ... more variable assignments

$output = $view->render('some script');
```

Then you can store $output in your database.

Comment: In controller you can use $this->view->render() - no need to create your own view instance.

Comment: It won't work for dynamically created view.In that case,how  can do this?
like i need to replace a value from view

Answer (score 5):

Simply use:

`$output = $this->view->render('controller/action.phtml');`

Comment: It won't work for dynamically created view.In that case,how can do this? like i need to replace a value from view

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but i tried and came up with a diferent solution:

```
$view = new Zend_View();
$view->some_var = "some_value";
$view->setScriptPath(APPLICATION_ROOT.'/layout/mail/');
$output = $view->render('led_inspira_inscricao_confirmada.phtml');
print_r($output);die;
```

where APPLICATION_ROOT is your real path at the first php file

```
define('APPLICATION_ROOT', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
```